# Avoid duplicate Bulk-New-ADUser Creation via a csv file

Tags: windows, powershell, csv

I have some modifications for this script. UserID is normally a user’s first name followed by their last name.
What I need to do is to compare the proxy address & SAMAccountName attribute associated with each Username before it create. 
So I mean lets say Jack Sparrow , if jsparrow already in use then script will try as jasparrow (first and second letter of firstname) and in use jasparrow as well , will be jacsparrow and so on. I want to avoid duplicate usernames.
2-I decided that it would be better to make 'fun' passwords that use the first two letters of the FirstName , day/month , first two letters of the Lastname. The end result is that users get a password like "Ja1009Sp".

```
Firstname,LastName,Department,Manager,MobilePhone
Jack,Sparrow,IT,jsmith,1 88 635 5254-0551
John Smith,Sparrow,Finance,jsmith,188 635 5254-0554
```

Script :

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$UserList = Import-CSV -Path C:\Temp\CreateUsers.csv
$targetOU='OU=usersOU,DC=My,DC=Domain,DC=org'
$upnDomain='sec.local'

foreach($Person in $UserList){
     $useritems=@{
          GivenName=$Person.Firstname
          Surname=$Person.LastName
          Department=$Person.Department
          AccountPassword=ConvertTo-SecureString -String $Person.Password -AsPlainText -force
          ChangePasswordAtLogon=$false
      Enabled=$true
          DisplayName="$($Person.Firstname) $($Person.Lastname)"
      Manager=$Person.Manager
      MobilePhone=$Person.MobilePhone
          Name="$($Person.Firstname) $($Person.Lastname)"
          SamAccountName="$($Person.Firstname+$Person.LastName.Substring(0,1))"
          UserPrincipalName="$($Person.FirstName+$Person.LastName.Substring(0,1))@$upnDomain"
      Company="Contoso"
     }

     New-ADUser  @useritems -Path $targetOU
}
```

Comment: Just FYI, your script would generate "JackS", not "JSparrow" as the username

Comment: thanks man actually I aware of this. BTW do you have any answer to my questions?

Comment: What if they're all in use including `JackSparrow`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this.. I don't have AD available atm. to test the `Get-ADUser`-query used to look for existing account so it might need some tuning.

```
foreach ($Person in $UserList) {

    #Reset counters
    $i = 1
    $n = 1

    do {
        if($i -le $person.Firstname.Length) {
            $user = "$($Person.Firstname.Substring(0,$i)+$Person.LastName)"
            $i++
        } else {
            #All combinations in use, adding number
            $user = "$($Person.Firstname.Substring(0,1)+$Person.LastName+$n)"
            $n++
        }
    } while ((Get-ADUser -Filter "(samAccountName -eq '$user') -or (proxyaddresses -like '$user*')"))

    #Result username
    #$user

    #$useritems = @{ 
        #.....
        #SamAccountName=$user
        #UserPrincipalName="$user@$upnDomain"
        #....
    #}


}
```

If all combinations are in use including `jacksparrow`, it tries `jsparrow1` ++ until it finds a free number.

The password can be generated using:

```
$Password = "{0}{1}{2}" -f $Person.Firstname.Substring(0,2), (Get-Date).ToString("ddMM"), $Person.Lastname.Substring(0,2)
```

Comment: thanks so much man BTW Where make sense to use Password variable? within useritems or before or after do while loop ?

Comment: `$password` needs to replace your current `$person.password` in the hashtable. Use it as the input for `convertto-securestring`

Comment: Lets say I want to be lowercase letter for 'j'  for SAMAccountName/UserPrincipalName such as jsparrow  Because I am using uppercase letter such as Jack Sparrow within CSV file. Would be any issue? Last question : I need to add the users to one or more security groups  too how can I do that?

Comment: Upn and Samaccountname are case-insensitive so it doesn't matter. You add users to groups using `Add-ADGroupMember` after creating the user.

Comment: $b = Get-Content C:\Groups.txt
Foreach($a in $b)
{
Add-Adgroupmember -identity $a -Members $user
} after new-aduser cmdlet I'll use it  Am I correct ?

Comment: That should work. I recommend testing this with a sample user and groups. The best way to learn is to try and fail (if unsure, use a test/lab environment)